# Disk Utility First Aid error

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, error

I got the following message when I try Disk Utility First Aid. Is there a way to fix the problem? (I have macOS 10.14.4.)

```
Running First Aid on “usbhd” (disk3s1)

Repairing file system.
Volume is already unmounted.
Performing fsck_hfs -fy -x /dev/rdisk3s1
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
Checking extents overflow file.
Checking catalog file.
The volume usbhd could not be verified completely.
File system check exit code is 8.
Restoring the original state found as unmounted.
File system verify or repair failed.

Operation failed…
```

Comment: "File system check exit code is 8" means your data is corrupted. The error message doesn't provide very much information, but it seems Disk Utility just doesn't understand the format of the disk.

Answer (score 1):

See: [File system check exit code is 8 on macOS](https://iboysoft.com/mac-data-recovery/file-system-check-exit-code-is-8.html)